# Set Table View Cell Height for Only One of Three Custom Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have three custom `TableViewCells`.  I have one of the three cells that I need to set `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for in code because I can't use AutoLayout in Storyboard for it.

**Is there a way to set `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for a *specific* custom `TableViewCell`?**

My `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.combinedModel[indexPath.row];

    // Custom Table View Cell Two
    if ([model isKindOfClass:[Data self]]) {

        return 500;
    }
    // Custom Table View Cell One and Three
    else {
        // Not sure what to put here, but need to put something without setting a height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do the following in my code:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.combinedModel[indexPath.row];

    // Custom Table View Cell Two
    if ([model isKindOfClass:[Data self]]) {
        return 500;
    } else {
        return tableView.rowHeight; // return the default height
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That makes sense and worked perfect!  Sadly I don't have enough rep to vote you up, but thank you!!

Comment: I'm actually getting this "jumping" behavior I didn't notice before when using that, any ideas?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948664/table-view-cells-jump-when-going-back-from-view-controller-to-table-view-contr/26949918#26949918

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea what you mean by that. Perhaps you should post another question with the appropriate details.

Comment: That was another question I posted with the appropriate details if you don't mind taking a peek at it.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems to actually be returning the hardcoded height of the cell when I return `tableView.rowHeight` instead of expanding or shrinking the cell based on the contents of the cell.  In that case what would you suggest if I didn't want it to return the defaulted `rowHeight`?

Answer (score 1):

"Put something without setting a height" doesn't make sense. You need to give the table view a height for every cell. Give it the default height you're using for other cells.

Comment: If I add any code in there, it overrides my Storyboard AutoLayout.  So if I put `return 200`, those cells seem to use `200` instead of using my Storyboard AutoLayout constraints and height.  Make sense or no?  Thanks!

Comment: And if nothing goes in the `else` part, then I get an error that it reaches end of non-void function.