# Table View Cells "jump" when going back from View Controller to Table View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I have a `TableViewController`, and clicking on a custom cell takes you to a related `WebViewController`.

The problem I'm having is that when I tap "Back" in the `WebViewController` the Table View Cells in `TableViewController` "jump".

[image]

*Once the Table View starts scrolling they all jump back into the right heights.  So I'm assuming it has something to do with heights on the `TableViewController` custom cells, but I'm not totally sure.*

**TableViewController.m**

Tried:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[Two self]]) {
        return 490; // As of 11/13/14
    } else { // 2 other custom cells
        return tableView.rowHeight; // return the default height
    }
}
```

Also Tried:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[One self]]) {
    ListTableViewCell *cellOne = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell"];
    CGFloat heightOne = [cellOne.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return heightOne + 2;

    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[Two self]]) {
    ListTableViewCellTwo *cellTwo = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"2Cell"];
    CGFloat heightTwo = [cellTwo.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return heightTwo + 400;

    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[Three self]]) {
    ListTableViewCellThree *cellThree = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"3Cell"];
    CGFloat heightThree = [cellThree.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return heightThree + 2;

    } else {
        return 300;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Also tried `[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` and `[cell setNeedsLayout];`.

Also have tried setting `estimatedHeight` multiple different spots, and also added `Automatic Row Dimension` in tandem with that.

Help would be appreciated!  Will post any extra info needed.  Thanks!

*I'm only supporting iOS 8.  I'm using Auto Layout and Storyboards.*

**Additional Storyboard info for Custom Cell 2:**
[image]
[image]

**Storyboard Constraints:**

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure just keep return 490; in the height method and remove anything else. What do you have?

Comment: was self.Model modified after showing WebViewController ?

Comment: @hasan83 Sorry I'm not sure I understood your sentence.  Are you saying to delete everything except return 490;?  Thanks!

Comment: @gottlieb no self.Model wasn't modified at all after showing WebViewController.  Any ideas?

Comment: How do you add WebViewController ? Using addSubview, presentViewController or pushing it into a navigation stack ?

Comment: @gottlieb pushing it into a navigation stack

Comment: What's your height constraint for the cell?

Comment: Also, just try "return 490" and see what the behavior is like hasan83 suggested

Comment: @hasan83 if I just `return 490` then cells don't jump anymore, but takes away what I was trying to do which was make `2Cell` taller height than `1Cell` and `3Cell`.  Does this make it clearer?  Thanks!

Comment: @AndyObusek Thanks for the response!  If I return 490 then the cells in the `TableViewController` don't jump anymore, but takes away what I was trying to do which was make 2Cell taller height than 1Cell and 3Cell.  This is why I was thinking, I need to figure out how to change the `heightForRowAtIndex` code or something, but I've tried two things I thought would be perfect and they didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve the issue yet?

Comment: @hasan83 not yet, table view cells are still "jumping" if I do anything other than hardcode a specific return height i.e. `return 175` in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you didn't set the constraint properly. I had the a problem similar to this before and solved by setting the constraints on Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom spacing to the UILabel.

Play around with the constraints. behavior will start change. keep going until you get what you want.

It doesn't seem as a decesnt technical answer from a professional. But, that how it getting solved with those dummy constraint which apple doesn't introduced properly.

Also, try **`[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];`** before you return cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
And: `[cell setNeedsLayout];`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just added a screenshot of my constraints to be helpful.  I've been playing around with the constraints A LOT thinking I might be setting them up wrong, but I can't get the constraints quite right even though there are no errors or warnings in the storyboard I guess.  I thought they were perfect, so that's why I'm looking in my code now to see if I'm missing something there.  Let me know if you see anything in my constraints that stands out to you?  Thanks!

Comment: For the label, only keep the constraints with the container. remove those with the image view. and tell me what is the new behaviour

Comment: If I have static values, it doesn't jump, but when I don't use static values it jumps.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this issue, the key is to calculate an estimated height. Seems like the more accurate estimate you return, the less jumpiness/choppiness.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     switch (yourTypeOfCell) {
         case something:
            return estimatedHeight;
            break;
         case default:
            return defaultValue;
            break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `estimatedRowHeight` in viewDidLoad for your UITableView to help UIKit guess your tableView's row height

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 490.0;
}
```

Comment: I'd tried that, but then commented it out because it didn't change the behavior of the table view cells "jumping" for me.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!